# Проверять элемент коллекции

Tags: android, kotlin, коллекции

На данный момент получаю коллекцию следующим образом:

```
override fun getListItems(context: Context): List<ConnectionViewModel> {
    return connectionsRepository.getAll().map { connection ->
        ConnectionViewModel(
                code = connection.code,
                name = connection.name,
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том чтобы проверить есть ли в моей коллекции уже элемент с таким именем(`connection.name`) и если есть, то вызвать метод который будет что то делать, например изменять поле `connection.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно в какой момент надо проверять совпадение имен соединений, и еще менее понятно почему при совпадении должно меняться имя соединения... Предположим, в процессе формирования списка вы хотите решить все конфликты имен. Тогда будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
override fun getListItems(context: Context): List<ConnectionViewModel> {
    val res = ArrayList<ConnectionViewModel>()
    for (connection  in connectionsRepository.getAll()){
        val collision = res.find {c -> c.name.contentEquals(connection.name)} 
        if(collision == null)
             res.add(ConnectionViewModel(code = connection.code, name = connection.name))
        else
            res.add(ConnectionViewModel(code = connection.code, name = "${connection.name}_new"))
    } 
}
```

Comment: правда теперь понял, что нужно еще проверять на коллизию с  "${connection.name}_new", но, думаю, разберетесь :)